# How to use xpath to get the text

Tags: html, xpath

I am new to Html and XPath. So I got this trouble.
If I want to get the text 'Saturday', what the xpath code should be like?
Thank you for your help!
The html like this.

```
<div class="D(ib) Va(m) W(1/4)" data-reactid=".28cjlo02kxy.$tgtm-Col1-0-Weather.2.$0.$0.1.1.$0.0">
<span data-reactid=".28cjlo02kxy.$tgtm-Col1-0-Weather.2.$0.$0.1.1.$0.0.0">Saturday
</span></div>
```

and then, if I want to get the title="Showers", what should I do next?

```
<span data-code="11" class="D(ib) Va(m) W(1/4) Ta(c)" data-reactid=".28cjlo02kxy.$tgtm-Col1-0-Weather.2.$0.$0.1.1.$1.1">
<img alt="Showers" height="32" title="Showers" width="32" class="Trsdu(.42s) " src="/sy/os/weather/1.0.1/shadow_icon/60x60/rain_day_night@2x.png" data-reactid=".28cjlo02kxy.$tgtm-Col1-0-Weather.2.$0.$0.1.1.$1.1.0"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is not enough information to provide a reliable XPath, but, given what we have, I'd have a partial match on `data-reactid` attribute(s):

```
//div[contains(@data-reactid, "Col1-0-Weather")]/span[contains(@data-reactid, "Col1-0-Weather")]
```

Comment: @alex.l great! Please make sure to accept the answer to resolve the topic. Thanks.